# ng-file-upload doesn't send file

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

I'm using ng-file-upload on my AngularJS app which uses an API as backend.

From postman i'm sending my parameters as form-data and my API is getting the file, as you can see in the image below: [image]

From my view, i'm using the following code:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <form ng-submit="update()">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{ 'name' | translate }}</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9"><input ng-model="account.name" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ 'entername' | translate }}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/><br/><br/>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{ 'logo' | translate }}</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div class="btn btn-default" ngf-select ng-model="file" name="file" ngf-pattern="'image/*'" ngf-accept="'imag e/*'" ngf-max-size="2MB">Select</div>
                <img ngf-thumbnail="file" class="img-responsive center-block" style="height:50px"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <div class="form-group text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="index()"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-close"></i> {{ 'cancel' | translate }} </button>
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-save"></i> {{ 'save' | translate }}</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

But from my angularjs app, it's not working! Practically i'm following the examples on github. My angularjs code is:

```
accountController.controller('accountEditController', function ($scope, Upload) {
$scope.update = function() {
    if ($scope.file)
        $scope.upload($scope.file);
};
$scope.upload = function (logo) {
    console.log(logo);
    Upload.upload({
        url: 'api/account/'+ $scope.id,
        method: 'PUT',
        file: logo,
        sendFieldsAs: 'form-data',
        fields: { name: $scope.name },
    }).then(function (resp) {
        console.log('Success uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
    }, function (resp) {
        console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
    }, function (evt) {
        var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
        console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ');
    });
};
```

});

From my console, I get these messages:

[image]

Comment: And... What happened after you uploaded the file?

Comment: I think you need to use form data
Refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19579576/append-files-to-formdata-not-work-in-angularjs

Comment: @AlonEitan nothing happens... It doesn't update anything even doesn't throw an error.

Comment: Please add the view to the question, and show us the declaration part of the controller in which you use this code. Also, open the developer tools and see if you get any JS errors

Comment: Thanks @AlonEitan I added relevant code to the question. From developers tools is not displayed any error.

Comment: Didn't find a specific problem. Are you sure the upload function is actually being called? Do you see in the console the result of `console.log(logo);` ?

Comment: @AlonEitan Yes, it's working fine. I edited the question and added an image which displays the result from console. Everything looks fine but it's not working.

Comment: Try changing `console.log('Success uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);` to `console.log('Success uploaded. Response: ', resp.data);` this will print what's inside the body of the response. It might be an error because when you manually upload the file you add properties such as `_method` and `token` which I'm not sure exist when you upload using angular

Comment: @AlonEitan You are right. Response is: Success uploaded. Response:  Object {message: "updated"}. There is no much information. I think I'll use another directive for this.